# C++ resolving using namespace std problems using modules

Tags: c++, c++-modules, c++23

As we know, using `using namespace std;` in header files is banned in all nontrivial projects. I hate this verbosity but understand its rationale behind.

However, I'm wondering if using C++20/23 modules could be a solution to this.

AFAIK declaring `using namespace std;` in global scope of headers has two biggest problems:

1. It pollutes the namespace of all users who include the header.
2. It pollutes the namespace of all identifiers within the header.

Personally I don't think the second problem is that severe, because the affected scope of identifiers is restricted within a single translation unit. So as far as I know the main reason why people are frowned upon is the first one.

And it seems to me that modules can solve the first one, like this:

```
export module frozenca;

import std.compat;

// ↓ I think this is definitely NOT OK
// export using namespace std;

// I think this is OK as this is not "propagated" outside of the module.
// Am I correct?
using namespace std; 

// .. other details ..
```

I couldn't find any implementation that the code above compiles, so I couldn't test.
Am I correct?

Comment: #2 is a _smaller_ problem than #1, but plenty of people will still say it's a problem. The idea is that even within a translation unit, `std::` doesn't actually take up that much extra space but it does communicate something valuable, namely "the identifier after this is part of the standard library, not my code or third-party library code". Especially for something like `queue` where it's a term reasonably likely to come up, it's a big boost to code readability.

Answer (score 2):

For the factual form of your question, you are correct. `using` directives declared in a module unit don't get exported to the interface of that unit. Therefore, they and their effects are locally contained within the module TU which declares them. An `import` will not `using namespace` anything.

And for what it's worth, you *cannot* `export using namespace` at all. That's a compile error.

---

That having been said, you should be aware that `std` contains a *lot* of names. Many of those names are short, single-word names like `begin` or `sort` and the like. Names that you might want to use yourself in certain places.

By bringing in the entirety of `std` into the local scope, you're opening yourself up to all kinds of potential conflicts.

`std::` is just five characters. Get used to them.